# Как адаптер для создания списка определяет тип View

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-binder

Не могу понять как написать универсальный биндер для SimpleAdapter.
Например код который добавляет возможность SimpleAdapter заполнить ProgressBar:

```
class MyViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
            int ii = 0;
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.llLoad:
                    if(((Integer) data).intValue() <40){
                        ii = getResources().getColor(R.color.Green);
                    }
                    else if(((Integer) data).intValue() <70){
                        ii = getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange);
                    }
                    else{
                        ii = getResources().getColor(R.color.Red);
                    }
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ii);
                    return true;
                case R.id.pbLoad:
                    ((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(Integer.parseInt(textRepresentation));
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Он работает сверяя ID полученного View с **заранее известными** ID(т.к мы заранее знаем с чем он должен будет работать).

Но как сделать ветвление не сверяя ID с нужными, а по типу переданного View, так чтобы выполнялся один код для всех переданных ProgressBar, независимо от ID?

Comment: `if (view instanceof НужныйТип) { НужныйТип widget = (НужныйТип) view;` и т.д. Для примера можете глянуть код самого `SimpleAdapter`: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d32d766a04ac9154a5465e7bceac3c8cbb5d77ab/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#L211

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то что надо)